# sql query date filtering the result

Tags: mysql, database

i've create a database to store statistics from a website such as traffic. i'm trying to query the database for the number of unique ip addresses that have been captured over the last 30 days;

```
SELECT COUNT(*) totalA FROM statistics GROUP by ipAddress 
AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE( ) ,INTERVAL 30 DAY) LIMIT 0, 30
```

however the query just return the number of data entry in the table. i've used the same query minus the date filter and gotten the correct result so it's just the date filtering thats messed up

any help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're `GROUP BY` on the `ipAddress AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE( ), INTERVAL 30 DAY)` and this expression yields the logical `AND` between two fields, which has only 2 possible values. Still, you don't care bout the distinction and request just `count(*)`.

What you probably want is:

```sql
SELECT ipAddress, DATE_SUB(CURDATE( ), INTERVAL 30 DAY), COUNT(*) AS totalA
  FROM statistics
 GROUP by ipAddress, DATE_SUB(CURDATE( ), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
 LIMIT 0, 30
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.  Basically I just put your date code in a WHERE clause and compared it to the date column in your table.  Obviously you will need to change the "entryDate" to whatever the name of your date column is.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalA
FROM statistics
WHERE entryDate >= DATE(CURDATE()-INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP BY ipAdress
```